# How to install MLR R frontend shinyMLR in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, r

Not in `apt search` but the package details [here](https://mlr-org.github.io/shinyMlr/). 
Found in OS X so should be in Linux too. 
You can install the backend as `sudo` in R prompt by `install.packages("mlr")`, docs [here](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/integrated_learners/) about the package.

### Trying to install shinyMlr by hhh's proposal

```
> devtools::install_github("mlr-org/shinyMlr/package")

Downloading GitHub repo mlr-org/shinyMlr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mlr-org/shinyMlr/zipball/master
Installing shinyMlr
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DT_0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 837622 bytes (817 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 817 KB

Installing DT
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools85045e441aa/DT'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests     
...    
Installing RWeka
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 656615 bytes (641 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 641 KB

Installing rJava
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools8504846fe1f/rJava'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
...
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.

Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
If in doubt, re-run "R CMD javareconf" as root.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RWekajars_3.9.1-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9915777 bytes (9.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 9.5 MB

Installing RWekajars
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 656615 bytes (641 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 641 KB

Skipping rJava, it is already being installed.
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools8501fe8748f/RWekajars'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘RWekajars’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RWekajars’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools850551cbf6d/RWeka'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependencies ‘RWekajars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘RWeka’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RWeka’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/shinyBS_0.61.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 26923 bytes (26 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 26 KB

Installing shinyBS
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools850747f9a75/shinyBS'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘shinyBS’ ...
** package ‘shinyBS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (shinyBS)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/shinydashboard_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 236005 bytes (230 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 230 KB

Installing shinydashboard
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools8501e8e169/shinydashboard'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘shinydashboard’ ...
...
Installing shinythemes
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools850c7e739e/shinythemes'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘shinythemes’ ...
** package ‘shinythemes’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (shinythemes)
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpIWf6Ri/devtools8503433e373/mlr-org-shinyMlr-a14be76/package'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency ‘RWeka’ is not available for package ‘shinyMlr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shinyMlr’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Errors in short

```
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘RWekajars’
ERROR: dependencies ‘RWekajars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘RWeka’
ERROR: dependency ‘RWeka’ is not available for package ‘shinyMlr’
```

I do successfully

- `sudo apt install r-cran-rjava`

Problems so I cannot find `rwekajars` and `rweka` in `apt`, but I can find them in `R` packages as `RWeka` and `RWekajars`

```
apt search rwekajars
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

apt search rweka
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

Running again `devtools::install_github("mlr-org/shinyMlr/package")` but succeeds this time!

```
> devtools::install_github("mlr-org/shinyMlr/package")
Downloading GitHub repo mlr-org/shinyMlr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mlr-org/shinyMlr/zipball/master
Installing shinyMlr
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpVr3BCI/devtools19bf36effb2d/mlr-org-shinyMlr-a14be76/package'  \
  --library='/home/masi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘shinyMlr’ ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: Installed Rcpp (0.12.12) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.11).
Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior.
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: Installed Rcpp (0.12.12) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.11).
Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior.
* DONE (shinyMlr)
>
```

But still the test code below fails similarly as with failed `runShinyMlr()` installation attempt.

### Trying to run runShinyMlr()

Test code

```
> runShinyMlr()
Error in runShinyMlr() : could not find function "runShinyMlr"
```

But still running the test code `runShinyMlr()`,  I get `could not find function`.

Exporting some packages successfully and then trying unsucessfully the test code

```
> library("RWeka")
> library("RWekajar")
Error in library("RWekajar") : there is no package called ‘RWekajar’
> library("runShinyMlr")
Error in library("runShinyMlr") : 
  there is no package called ‘runShinyMlr’
> runShinyMlr()
Error in runShinyMlr() : could not find function "runShinyMlr"
```

### Trying to install explicitly `runShinyMlr()` explicitly

Doing in the R prompt the following as `sudo` fails too.

```
> install.packages("runShinyMlr")
Installing package into ‘/home/masi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package ‘runShinyMlr’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
```

### Trying to update Java configs by hhh's proposal

The command `sudo R CMD javareconf` fails with a fatal error. 
Solution to the problem - just install JDK like the following so this one work now!

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Runs properly

```
sudo R CMD javareconf 
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_131
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/jranke/git/r-backports/stretch/r-base-3.4.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Outputs of the compilers - which test files do you want?

```
masi@masi:~/Desktop/Machine.learning.R$ /usr/bin/gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

masi@masi:~/Desktop/Machine.learning.R$ /usr/bin/java
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
...

masi@masi:~/Desktop/Machine.learning.R$ /usr/bin/gfortran
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I have no `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

```
vim /home/masi/.bash
.bash_history  .bash_logout   .bashrc
```

OS: Debian 9
R: 3.4.0

Comment: What have you done and where did it fail? What error messages?

Comment: This is the error, you are misreading me `> library("runShinyMlr")
Error in library("runShinyMlr") : 
  there is no package called ‘runShinyMlr’` -- you should have `library(shinyMlr)` and then try `runShinyMlr()`.

Comment: @hhh Correct! Thank you! It works that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly in R with devtools such that

```
devtools::install_github("mlr-org/shinyMlr/package")
```

and you start it with

```
library(shinyMlr)
shinyMlr::runShinyMlr()
```

further information [here](https://github.com/mlr-org/shinyMlr).

**Other things to try**

1. Because shinyMlr requires the rJava, you may want to update your java configs in R with

   ```
   sudo R CMD javareconf
   ```

also you may need to install the newest Java JDK. You can get the JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). To check up that you have JDK installed, you should have command line tools like below

```
$ /usr/bin/javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...] Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -parameters                Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -h <directory>             Specify where to place generated native header files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -profile <profile>         Check that API used is available in the specified profile
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  -Werror                    Terminate compilation if warnings occur
  @<filename>                Read options and filenames from file
```

2. If this did not work, then try `"mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile_backup"` so that your path is not intercepted by some your path variables.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 test first `library(shinyMlr); runShinyMlr()`, does it work? Alas, can you restart your editor/terminal? An environment command such as `env` in macOS can also reveal potential errors. You could also try moving dot files in `~` to elsewhere for a while and then try the installation -- if it does not fail, then there was some path variable mixing the installation.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 you may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131343/rjava-linker-error-licuuc-with-anaconda-fopenmp-error-without-anaconda-for-mac) about what it looks with me. I think there is something wrong, it looks like a compiler issue. Can you run `/usr/bin/gcc`, `/usr/bin/java`, `/usr/bin/gfortran` -- I think you should ask a new question on getting the java configs correct, otherwise you may get odd errors or bad compilations later (I am not anymore using Anaconda so the configs there are a bit old).

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 that is irrelevant -- you have Java command line tools (so apparently Java JDK installed) and other compliers seem to working. This is a compiler error and you should ask a new question on this. The error seems to be in gcc compiler.

Comment: Correct! Missing JDK in the system. Now, runs properly, please see the body. Any other tests which I should do?